# Firebase in Ionic 3 project

Tags: firebase, ionic3, angular5

When I try running my ionic project, with `ionic serve` or  `ionic cordova run android --device`, the following error shows up:

> typescript: node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/esm/src/api/Database.d.ts, line: 4
>   
>  Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private'.

I have no idea why this is happening. Also, I recently upgrade to Angular 5, don't know if that has something to do.

Here is my package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/admob-free": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "9.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.0",
    "@types/google-maps": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.30.0",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-admob-sdk": "^0.11.1",
    "cordova-android": "^6.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "1.7.0",
    "cordova-plugin-admob-free": "^0.11.0",
    "cordova-plugin-browsertab": "^0.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-buildinfo": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme": "^4.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^1.9.1",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm": "^2.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^4.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.6.3",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "^2.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-promise-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "cordova-universal-links-plugin": "^1.2.1",
    "firebase": "^4.6.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.5",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },


  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.3",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.2",
    "@types/node": "8.0.57",
    "codecov": "^1.0.1",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "connect": "3.6.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.8.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^3.2.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.4",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "4.1.1",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  },
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked if the file `@firebase/app-types/private` exists? Maybe you need to re-install the packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this error is due to the recent firebase package release (4.8.1), where they refactored the typing setup. Forcing the firebase package to version 4.8.0 should solve your problem.

Comment: I actually downgraded to ^4.6.0, but I'll try your answer

Comment: This did the trick, thank you so much @timsuldat